# Why they collect coffee beans that are eaten by wild civets? Why don't they use fresh coffee beans instead of collecting these unhygienic beans.

Tags: coffee-culture, kopiluwak

How is this possible to collect coffee beans that were eaten by wild civets in forest? Is it  hygienic? Why so expensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason to collect these beans is flavor. Passing through the digestive system changes the flavor of the beans. I have never personally tasted it, but I have heard that the beans have a sweet caramel like flavor. As long as the beans are roasted, it is perfectly hygienic.

Answer (score 0):

The coffee bean we brew our coffee from is the seed of a fruit and the flesh of that fruit must first be removed. There are a number of industrial / cottage industry means for processing the fruit for the bean, but the civet's digestive system also does the job. :) The beans are raised well above the 140F needed to kill bacteria during the roasting process before we brew coffee from them, so no worries about the hygienics unless you're brewing green beans.